# Scraping framework with xpath support

Tags: xpath, css-selectors, web-scraping

I'm looking for a web scraping framework that lets me

1. Hit a given endpoint and load the html response
2. Search for elements by some css selector
3. Recover the xpath for that element

Any suggestions?  I've seen many that let me search by xpath, but none that actually generate the xpath for an element.

Comment: Which languages are you limited to, if any?

Comment: Any language is fine.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at the answer I posted? The JQuery example is easy but would need to be implemented in Node.js which I can't help further on besides the material I linked to which explains some about using JQuery in that domain. Python example is complete, but not technically a web scraping framework. The C# example is actually from HTMLAgilityPack which is an entire web scraping framework.

Comment: I'm still working through it; the answer is a lot more detailed (and of higher quality) than I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be true that not many people search by CSS selector yet want a result as an XPath instead, but there are some options to get there.

First I wound up doing this with JQuery plus an additional function. This is because JQuery has pretty nice selection and is easy to find support for. You can [use JQuery in Node.js](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-nodejs-and-jquery--net-22478), so you should be able to implement my code in that domain (on a server) instead of on the client (as shown in my simple example). If that's not an option, you can look below for my other potential solution using Python or at the bottom for a C# starter.

---

For the **JQuery** approach, the pure JavaScript function is pretty simple for returning the XPath. In the following example ([also on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/syqabz9p/1/)) I retrieved the example anchor element with the JQuery selector, got the stripped DOM element, and sent it to my `getXPath` function:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>The jQuery Example</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" 
   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function getXPath( element )
    {
        var xpath = '';
        for ( ; element && element.nodeType == 1; element = element.parentNode )
        {
            var id = $(element.parentNode).children(element.tagName).index(element) + 1;
            id > 1 ? (id = '[' + id + ']') : (id = '');
            xpath = '/' + element.tagName.toLowerCase() + id + xpath;
        }
        return xpath;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#example").click(function() {
            alert("Link Xpath: " + getXPath($("#example")[0]));
        });
    });

   </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <p id="p1">This is an example paragraph.</p>
    <p id="p2">This is an example paragraph with a <a id="example" href="#">link inside.</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

There is a full library for more robust CSS selector to XPath conversions called [css2xpath](https://code.google.com/p/css2xpath/) if you need more complexity than what I provided.

---

**Python (lxml):**
For Python you'll want to use lxml's CSS selector class [(see link for full tutorial and docs)](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html) to get the xml node.

> **The CSSSelector class**
>
> The most important class in the lxml.cssselect module is CSSSelector.
>   It provides the same interface as the XPath class, but accepts a CSS
>   selector expression as input:

```
>>> from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
>>> sel = CSSSelector('div.content')
>>> sel  #doctest: +ELLIPSIS <CSSSelector ... for 'div.content'>
>>> sel.css
'div.content'
```

> The selector actually compiles to XPath, and you can see the
>   expression by inspecting the object:

```
>>> sel.path
"descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' content ')]"
```

> To use the selector, simply call it with a document or element object:

```
>>> from lxml.etree import fromstring
>>> h = fromstring('''<div id="outer"> 
...   <div id="inner" class="content body"> 
...       text 
...   </div></div>''')
>>> [e.get('id') for e in sel(h)]
['inner']
```

> Using CSSSelector is equivalent to translating with cssselect and
>   using the XPath class:

```
>>> from cssselect import GenericTranslator
>>> from lxml.etree import XPath
>>> sel = XPath(GenericTranslator().css_to_xpath('div.content'))
```

> CSSSelector takes a translator parameter to let you choose which
>   translator to use. It can be 'xml' (the default), 'xhtml', 'html' or a
>   Translator object.

If you're looking to load from a url, you can do that directly when building the etree: `root = etree.fromstring(xml, base_url="http://where.it/is/from.xml")`

---

**C#** 
There is a library called [css2xpath-reloaded](https://bitbucket.org/MostThingsWeb/css2xpath-reloaded/) which does nothing but CSS to XPath conversion.

```
String css = "div#test .note span:first-child";

String xpath = css2xpath.Transform(css);

// 'xpath' will contain:
// //div[@id='test']//*[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' note ')]*[1]/self::span
```

Of course, getting a string from the url is very easy with C# utility classes and needs little discussion:

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
   string s = client.DownloadString(url);
}
```

As for the selection with CSS Selectors, you could try [Fizzler](https://code.google.com/p/fizzler/), which is pretty powerful. Here's the front page example, though you can do much more:

```
// Load the document using HTMLAgilityPack as normal
var html = new HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(@"
  <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <div>
          <p class='content'>Fizzler</p>
          <p>CSS Selector Engine</p></div>
      </body>
  </html>");

// Fizzler for HtmlAgilityPack is implemented as the 
// QuerySelectorAll extension method on HtmlNode

var document = html.DocumentNode;

// yields: [<p class="content">Fizzler</p>]
document.QuerySelectorAll(".content"); 

// yields: [<p class="content">Fizzler</p>,<p>CSS Selector Engine</p>]
document.QuerySelectorAll("p");

// yields empty sequence
document.QuerySelectorAll("body>p");

// yields [<p class="content">Fizzler</p>,<p>CSS Selector Engine</p>]
document.QuerySelectorAll("body p");

// yields [<p class="content">Fizzler</p>]
document.QuerySelectorAll("p:first-child");
```